# What is the name of the category that describes all the ways a number can be read?

Tags: linguistics, phonetics

Written numbers can be read aloud in multiple different ways:

1. Nominal numbers can be read by pronouncing each digit individually: "My phone number is 123456" read as "one, two, three..."
2. Nominal numbers can also be read by [chunking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunking_(psychology)) digits together where each chunk is read as a separate whole number: "123456" read as "twelve, thirty-four, fifty-six"
3. Cardinal numbers can be read as whole numbers: "I'm 40 years old" read as "Forty"
4. Ordinal number where digits are read as a single number but in a way that is different from cardinal numbers: "February 25, 1991" read as "Twenty-fifth"

What is the name of the linguistic or phonetic category that describes all the different ways a number can be read?

Comment: This confuses 'way in which a numeral is used' with 'way in which a numeral is pronounced'. You could read aloud your example phone number (a nominal usage) as "twelve thirty-four fifty-six" say, and confirm a cardinal number "We have fifty, that's five-oh, doses of vaccine left" using a different mode of expression. // Are you requesting a term fitting "This number is being used either as a cardinal or a nominal number; what would you say its ----- is?"?

Comment: There's a process for remembering and saying numbers called _number chunking_, but I'm not sure what you are asking here.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Sorry for the late reply (and the unclear wording). I'm purely interested in the phonetic aspect of number reading. So reading nominal number as a series of 2-digit cardinals would certainly fall under the category I'm looking for. I'll edit my question to clarify.

Comment: @Cascabel Thank you for mentioning [Number Chunking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunking_(psychology)). While chunking can describe how nominal numbers are read, it doesn't cover how cardinal and ordinal numbers are read. What I want is a category that encompasses all the ways numbers are read. I'll try to clarify my question further.

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/92589/transcribing-long-repeating-phone-numbers/92771#92771) and [also related](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/216898/911-nine-one-one-vs-nine-eleven/216903#216903). // I've a strong suspicion that the optimal descriptor the lengthy one you use in your revised title. << category: all the ways a [whole, real, non-negative] number can be read out >>  But note that numbers include vulgar etc fractions, recurring and terminating decimals, percentage representations (250% = 2·5 = 2½) ... irrationals (eg √2) ...  complex numbers ....

Comment: I've asked this question again [in the linguistics section](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/37964/what-is-the-name-of-the-category-that-describes-the-ways-a-number-can-be-read). I'll update this question if I get an answer.